# Rename intel tag to intel-cpu

Tags: discussion

Since companies tags are useless, we need something for Intel CPU products. We already have intel-graphics, intel-wireless, intel-[insert your product here], so renaming the tag seems like the Right Thing To Do™ to prevent ambiguity and be consistent with the [general policy of SE.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254124/792066)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the ambiguity but the problem here is we can't simply merge (what I read by "rename"). The tag is *full* of all sorts of Intel-related questions, not just CPUs. It's probably contains more about GPUs than CPUs but anyway.

I will send an email off to SE requesting they put a block on the Intel tag that recommends [intel-cpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel-cpu), [intel-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel-graphics) or [intel-wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel-wireless). It won't fix past instances but it'll stop new ones. We have something similar on [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation).

Comment: So, manual cleanup... there goes another weekend :(